# mod_rewrite REQUEST_URI confusion

Tags: linux, apache, mod-rewrite, ssl

I want to force `ssl` access on an entire site, except for the following pages:

- `www.example.com/loans_and_lines/home_loans.html www.example.com/cards`
- `www.example.com/cards/international-ministries.html`
- `www.example.com/cards/international-ministries/donation-3.html`
- `www.example.com/locations_and_contacts/`

**Force `ssl`:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/personal/loans_and_lines/home_loans\.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cards/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cards/international\-ministries\.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cards/international\-ministries/donation\-3\.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/locations_and_contacts/$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

However neither of the `/cards` or `/locations_and_contacts` and any of the pages are being excluded from being served with `ssl` access. Can someone tell me what's wrong with my set of rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:)

...

You forgot the "OR" directive. Here's what should work (and maybe you've forgotten the QSA directive in the redirect as well (maybe not)):

```
# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/personal/loans_and_lines/home_loans\.html [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cards/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cards/international\-ministries\.html [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cards/international\-ministries/donation\-3\.html [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/locations_and_contacts/$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

### Two hints:

---

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

Comment: Wow, I completely forgot about the [OR] directive.

Comment: You could optimize your rewrite cond in 2 line, but it would be less "readable".

Comment: `[OR]` would not work in this particular example, as it would still redirect ALL requests to HTTPS.

Comment: There are comments on your answer which were posted as answers: http://i.stack.imgur.com/i8piK.png

Comment: Your answer seems logically wrong to me. You must not use `[OR]` as the options are mutually exclusive. This will trigger each request.